# How to use BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION correctly?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-exception

I try to use boost exceptions and fall.
There are the problem code:

```
struct exception_base : virtual std::exception, virtual boost::exception 
{
    exception_base(std::exception&& e)
        : std::exception(e)
    {}
};

int main()
{
    std::string exception_description;

    try
    {
        BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(exception_base(std::runtime_error("hello exception")));
    }
    catch (exception_base& ex)
    {
        exception_description = boost::diagnostic_information(ex);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In this case the value of the exception_description have the last string - "**std::exception::what: Unknown exception**". It is unexpected value. If I change BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION to usual throw - the last string of exception_description value looks expected - "**std::exception::what: hello exception**"

So how to use BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom exception class is not necessary, and is the root cause of your problems.  If you remove it you can just do this:

```
BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(std::runtime_error("hello exception"));
```

Then:

```
catch (const std::exception& ex)
```

And the code will work the way you expect.

Why was it not working before?  Well, your `exception_base` class has no storage for the error message, so when you construct it from a `std::exception` it cannot store the message (e.g. from the original `runtime_error`).

You could fix it a lot of different ways, but ultimately they will boil down to the same thing: if you want your custom exception class to contain a message string, it must somehow contain that message string.

I'm a fan of not defining custom exception types 95% of the time, so I'd advise you to just keep it simple and use `runtime_error` (and/or `logic_error`).

Note that `BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION` automatically adds `boost::exception` as a base class for the thrown type, so you do not need to do that yourself anyway--there's no advantage.

---

other things:

- at your catch site use `std::cerr << boost::diagnostic_information(ex) << std::endl;` and that will print all the metadata that `BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION` adds on like: file, line, function, etc
- if you are throwing a `std::exception` inside of the `BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION()` you can wrap your `std::exception` with `boost::enable_error_info()` to change the type to `boost::exception` and that allows you to enrich the exception with other arbitrary fields via `operator<<`

Comment: Hi John, you dont get my point. It is the moust simple code that describe the trouble. I need the additional boost exception futures as line number, function name, filename where exception appears. So I need to use the class exception_base in the way as described in the boost documentation. Also for boost futures I need to use BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION instead plain throw keyword.

Comment: If you try the code I suggested, you will find that it does support line number, function name, and file name where the exception was thrown.  All that is done automatically by `BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION`.  Try it!

Comment: I got you point. Your code just needs some fix - there must be boost::exception in the catch instead std::exception. With std::exception it is not works on my side, but with boost it works. BUT! If I need the custom exception - what I can do?

Comment: Also I dont get your point about "class has no storage for the error message" - why? It is derived from std::exception - so it has all functionality of the std::exception

Comment: If you absolutely must have a custom exception class, then you need to implement it properly, storing the message inside.  You could do this by deriving from `runtime_error` or by adding a `std::string` inside the class and storing the message there.  `std::exception` has no error message inside it--you can know this by observing that it has no constructor which accepts a string.